# How do I configure Time Machine to backup my Macs to iCloud?

Tags: icloud, backup, time-machine

I have the 2 TB iCloud storage plan and back up my iPhones and iPads there. How do I configure Time Machine to do the same with my MacBook Pro's and Mac Mini's?

Comment: I found this... https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182223/is-it-possible-to-use-time-machine-with-icloud?rq=1, which still doesn't answer the question. I'm determined to find a way to do this, even if I have to pull something out of my...USB port...

Comment: There must be a script or something that can be made to work.

Comment: My comment on the linked post still applies - just get Backblaze [CrashPlan is gone, except for corporate].

Answer (score 1):

You cannot officially back up a Mac to iCloud at this time.

If you want to write a program that does this, you could utilize CloudKit. This would be beyond the scope of a single Stack Overflow question, so I'll just link to the CloudKit documentation here:

https://developer.apple.com/icloud/cloudkit/

Comment: Well, that's not an acceptable answer.!

Comment: Acceptable or not I believe Ezekiel is correct.

Comment: @BillSmith I've revised my answer to explore a possiblity

Comment: Better answer, but I'm holding out for someone to try to make it work. I know the Time Machine protocol is based on SMB. It's pretty hard to believe that nobody has created a product that munges the two together.

Comment: @BillSmith TimeMachine does work over SMB, by nature of creating a Sparse Disk Image on the receiving end. It would likely be easier to implement a custom backup program then to make time machine backup over a fake SMB connection to a fake Sparse Bundle.

Comment: @EzekielElin So, how long do you think it'll take you to get it done? ;-)